# How can I specify the type of a property in an inherited entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have recently started to use entity framework on projects, and I was wondering on how to model a specific case.

Consider this scenario :

- My application needs to model several types of contracts
- Every type of contract contains one or more instances of subcontracts
- Every type of contract exposes its subcontracts in a collection
- Every type of contract can only contain subcontracts of a specific type corresponding to the one of the contract (A contract of type `ContractA` will only contain subcontracts of type `SubcontractA`, a contract of type `ContractB` will only contain subcontracts of type `SubcontractB`)

What would be the best way to model this in an entity framework model ?

My first try used an association between the base types, but I wanted to be able to specify the type of Subcontracts on each derived type of Contract, without having two different properties on the specific type of Contract.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation recently. I ended up setting the association between the base types only and adding validation to the entities to make sure the properties contains only the right subtypes. Check out [IValidatableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx).

The drawbacks are that this happens at runtime, so a programmer could assign the wrong type and they won't find out until they test. It also requires casting the objects to the right types to use them. It was the best option I could come up with though.

I'd love to know if someone has a better solution.